# high variance with Randomforest learner

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest, variance

I'm using Random Forest Regressor to fit a 10-dimensional regression problem with around 300 thousand samples. Although not necessary when dealing with Random Forest I started by putting the data on the same scale (by using preprocessing of sklearn) and then I did a randomised search over the following parameter space:

```
    n_estimators=[int(x) for x in linspace (start=100, stop= 2000, num=11)]
    max_features= auto, sqrt
    max_depth= from 1- to 150 with step =11
    min_sampl_split=2,5,10,12
    min_samples_leaf=1,2,4,6
    Bootstrap true or false
```

Moreover, after getting the best parameters I did a second narrower search. 
Though I am using a 10-Fold cross validation scheme with the random search I'm still getting a serious overfitting problem! 
Moreover, I have also tried using DBSCAN algorithm to check for outliers. After excluding some parts of the dataset I got even worse results!
Should I include other parameters of the Random Forest in the randomised search? or should I apply some more preprocessing techniques on the data set before fitting?

For convenience, this is my implementation I wrote:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import ShuffleSplit
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import RandomizedSearchCV
n_estimators = [int(x) for x in np.linspace(start = 1, stop = 
15, num = 15)]
max_features = ['auto', 'sqrt']
max_depth = [int(x) for x in np.linspace(10, 110, num = 11)]
max_depth.append(None)
min_samples_split = [2, 5, 10,12]
min_samples_leaf = [1, 2, 4,6]
bootstrap = [True, False]
cv = ShuffleSplit(n_splits=10, test_size=0.01, random_state=0)

random_grid = {'n_estimators': n_estimators,
               'max_features': max_features,
               'max_depth': max_depth,
               'min_samples_split': min_samples_split,
               'min_samples_leaf': min_samples_leaf,
               'bootstrap': bootstrap}
rf = RandomForestRegressor()
rf_random = RandomizedSearchCV(estimator = rf, param_distributions 
= random_grid, n_iter = 50, cv = cv, verbose=2, random_state=42, 
n_jobs = 32)
rf_random.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

the best parameters returned by the randomizedsearch function:
bootstrap: Fasle. Min_samples_leaf=2. n_estimators= 1647. Max_features: sqrt. min_samples_split=3. Max_depth: None.

The range of the target is from 0 to 10000 [unit]. This model is resulting in 6.98 [unit] RMSE accuracy on the training set and and average of 67.54 [unit] RMSE accuracy on the test sets.

Answer (score 0):

that line

`max_depth= from 1- to 150 with step =11`

For a 10 feature problem, the optimum depth is under 10. You are overfitting like crazy beacause of that. consider putting max_depth from 1 to 15 with step 1

```
min_sampl_split=2,5,10,12
min_samples_leaf=1,2,4,6
```

This should help reduce the variance, however, the step of 11 for max_depth is killing all the efforts you could possibly make

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried to tune again using the range you specified but this didn't result in a better model. It's still overfitting :/

Comment: can you show results and why you think you overfit. Your code for 10-Fold would be appreciated also. Because right now i can't tell what the problem is.

Comment: The range of the target (the value I want to predict) is from 0 to 10000 [unit]. This model is resulting in 6.98 [unit] RMSE accuracy on the training set and and average of 67.54 [unit] RMSE accuracy on the test sets.
for implementing the 10-fold I just used ShuffleSplit from sklearn. For convenience I added my implementation and the best parameters to the post above.

Comment: could you try with rf_random = RandomizedSearchCV(estimator = rf, param_distributions 
= random_grid, n_iter = 50, cv = 10, verbose=2, random_state=42, 
n_jobs = 32)

Comment: same  results :/